# How to fix the Argument of type 'Date[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(prevState: undefined) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to build my project. but there's an error which is the `Argument of type 'Date[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(prevState: undefined)`

here's the code:

```
    const [ dateRange, setDateRange] = useState();
    
    const handleChange = (value, type?) => {
            let FILTER = { from: format(subHours(new Date(), value), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), to: format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') }

        setDateRange([new Date(FILTER['from']),new Date(FILTER['to'])])
    };

    return (<>
    <DateRangePicker
                        className="uppercase"
                        value={dateRange}
                        placeholder={'Start ~ End'}
                        ranges={[
                            {
                                label: 'today',
                                value: [startOfDay(new Date()), endOfDay(new Date())]
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'yesterday',
                                value: [
                                    startOfDay(addDays(new Date(), -1)),
                                    endOfDay(addDays(new Date(), -1))
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'last7Days',
                                value: [startOfDay(subDays(new Date(), 6)), endOfDay(new Date())]
                            }
                        ]}
                        onOk={(value) => handleChange(value, 'dateRange')}
                    />
</>)
```

I used state for the value of daterange and added `handleChange function` when I'm changing the date range.

But when I try to build it show the error which is Type 'Date[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'

UPDATED:

```
interface DataRange {
    from: Date,
    to: Date,
}

    const initalState: DataRange[] = [{from: new Date(), to: new Date()}]
    const [ dateRange, setDateRange] = useState(initalState);
        const newDateRange = [{from: new Date(FILTER['from']), to: new Date(FILTER['to'])}];
        setDateRange(newDateRange)
```

but there's an error on the daterangepicker:

```
Type 'DataRange[]' is not assignable to type '[Date?, Date?]'.

Types of property 'length' are incompatible.

Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 1 | 2'.
```

Comment: For ```FILTER```,  you need to declare it like ```const FILTER = ...```?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 forgot to add the ```let```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the default value to `useState()` and also clearly declare the type.

````
interface DateRange{
   to: Date, 
   from: Date
}

const initialState: DateRange[] = //initial DateRange array

const [ dateRange, setDateRange] = useState(initialState);


 const handleChange = (value, type?) => {
       let FILTER = { from: format(subHours(new Date(), value), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), to: format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') }

       const newDateRange = [...dateRange, /*add the value you need*/] // you can make a new Date Range here, after you have finish constructing, then passed it to the ```setDateRange```

       setDateRange(newDateRange)
};
````

Comment: in react hooks it will be like this? ```setDateRange((prevState) => ([...prev, /*add the value need here*/]))```?

Comment: Updated the answer, for the ```newDateRange```, I mean you can grab the old ```dataRange``` state and adding the value. Using ```prevState``` should be fine but the callback will be long, considering you may do some operation for updating your ```dateRange```

Comment: the ```setDateRange``` should be ```setDateRange[from, to]``` cause there's an error which is the ```Type 'DataRange[]' is not assignable to type '[Date?, Date?]'.``` on the ```daterangepicker```

Comment: I think your each dateRange should contain ```from``` and ```to```. From your code, I see that you may contain the dateRange of today, yesterday,  7 days... Therefore, the ```dateRange``` of your state should be an array with ```dateRange``` object.  Like [{from: date1, to: date2}, {from: date3, to: date4 }.....]

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Also, if it available, you can put your code on jsFiddle and attach the link here. So that we can modify the code tgt.

Comment: But there's an error in the ```datepicker``` which is the ```value={dateRange}```. which is the ```Type 'DataRange[]' is not assignable to type '[Date?, Date?]'.
  Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 1 | 2'.```